# Linking a custom Android activity/view to React Native

Tags: android, react-native

### Problem

The majority of my app is on React Native and am currently transitioning to complete native builds (iOS and Android). I have decided to do it piecemeal and only build certain components at a time. One of the components I have is representative of [Androids Bottom Sheet Behavior](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/). Real life examples include Lyft's new design. The BottomSheet component is not showing even though I set the peek height. [image: Lyft].

### Attempted Solution

I am still getting accustomed to Android Studio and building apps for Android, so very flexible to hear about improvements to my approach. Should I be using a ViewGroup? Should I be using an activity and if so is it possible to run 2 activities at the same time (Like in terms of the Lyft photo above is the map view 1 activity and the bottom sheet a separate activity?)?

**BottomSheetView**

```
public class BottomSheetView extends ViewGroup {

    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;

    public BottomSheetActivity(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet, this);
        CoordinatorLayout coordinaterLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinate_layout);
        View bottomSheet = coordinaterLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_component);
        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
    }
}
```

**BottomSheetManager**

```
public class BottomSheetManager extends ViewGroupManager<BottomSheetView> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "BottomSheet";

    private BottomSheetView bottomSheet;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected BottomSheetView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new BottomSheetView(reactContext);
    }

}
```

**BottomSheetPackage**

```
...
@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(new BottomSheetManager());
}
```

**React Native**

```
import react, { Component } from 'react';
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';
const BottomSheet = requireNativeComponent('BottomSheet', SomeClass);

class SomeClass extends Component {
    render() {
      return (<BottomSheet />);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem and fixed using a **Fragment**.
The current **React Native version (0.66)** have information with sample code about how to implement it:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#1-create-a-fragment